# how to open a modal using redux & react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

Trying to figure out redux. I want to open a modal from my home container. I have been trying to follow some tutorials but I am not seeing any errors so I am need some help. I am stuck with the modal component listening or subscribing to the store. I need to pass a payload object as well.

UPDATE:

trying to troubleshoot this I realized that unless I change routes after making the dispatch the targeted component will not receive any props. 
What I did: I moved the receiveProps code from the modal component and placed in a actual route component.

```
    openRouteSummary(data) {
        this.props.openRouteSummary(data);
        this.replaceRoute('subdivisions')
    }
```

Actions/

type.js

```
   export type Action =
  { type: 'OPEN_DRAWER' }
  | { type: 'CLOSE_DRAWER' }
  | { type: 'OPEN_MODAL' }

export type Dispatch = (action: Action | ThunkAction | PromiseAction | Array<Action>) => any;
export type GetState = () => Object;
export type ThunkAction = (dispatch: Dispatch, getState: GetState) => any;
export type PromiseAction = Promise<Action>;
```

modal.js

```
import type {Action } from './types';

export const OPEN_MODAL = "OPEN_MODAL";

export function openModal(data): Action {
     return {
        type: OPEN_MODAL,
        payload: data,
    }
}
```

reducers/

modal.js

```
import type {Action } from '../actions/types';
import { OPEN_MODAL, CLOSE_MODAL} from '../actions/modal';

export type State = {
    isOpen: boolean,
    payload: Object
}

const initialState = {
    isOpen: false,
    payload: {}
};

export default function (state: State = initialState, action: Action): State {
    if (action.type === OPEN_MODAL) {
        return {
        ...state,
            payload: action.payload.data,
            isOpen: true
        };
    }
      if (action.type === CLOSE_MODAL) {
        return {
        ...state,
            isOpen: false
        };
    }
    return state;
}
```

Container/

home.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {openModal} from '../../actions/modal';

import Summary from './../modals/summary';

class Home extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);


    openModal(data) {
        this.props.openModal(data);
    }

     render() {
        return (
            <Container theme={theme}>
                 <Content>
                        <Grid>
                            <Row>
                                <Col style={{ padding: 20 }}>
                                    <Button transparent onPress={() => this.openModal({ rowData: 'rowData' }) }>
                                        <Text>
                                            Open Modal
                                        </Text>
                                    </Button>
                                </Col>
                            </Row>
                        </Grid>
                 </Content>

                <Summary/>
            </Container>
        )
    }
}

function bindAction(dispatch) {
    return {
        openModal: (data) => dispatch(openModal(data))
    }
}

export default connect(null, bindAction)(Home);
```

modal.js

```
/* @flow */

'use strict';

import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {openModal} from '../../actions/modal';
import Modal from 'react-native-modalbox';

class Summary extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            model: {}
        };
    }
    componentDidMount() {

    }

    openModal(data) {
        console.log(data)
        //this.setState({ model: data })
        this.refs.modal.open();
    }

    _close() {
        this.refs.modal.close();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Modal
                backdropOpacity={.8}
                style={[styles.modal, { height: 280, width: 280 }]}
                ref={"modal"}
                swipeToClose={false}
                backdropPressToClose={false}>
                <Container theme={theme}>
                    <Content padder>
                        <Grid>
                            <Row>
                                <Col style={styles.header}>
                                    <Text style={styles.headerText}>Survey Summary</Text>
                                </Col>
                            </Row>
                        </Grid>
                    </Content>
                </Container>
            </Modal>
        );
    }
}

function bindAction(dispatch) {
    return {
        openModal: (data) => dispatch(openModal(data))
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        payload: state.modal.payload
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, bindAction)(Summary);
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to connect the `Modal.js` component and add a `componentWillReceiveProps` lifecycle method. In this method, you check if the `openModal` property from your reducer changed. If so you need to act accordingly (open / close the modal) otherwise just ignore it.

**Edit**: Example for `Modal.js`

This is how `Modal.js` may look like. By connecting I meant using redux's connect method, what you already did. The last line has two action creators `openModal` & `closeModal`, which would you need to import.

```
    /* @flow */

    'use strict';

    ....

    class Summary extends Component {
        ...
        componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
            if(nextProps.modalOpen !== this.props.modalOpen) {
                if (nextProps.modalOpen) {
                    this.openModal();
                } else {
                    this.closeModal()M
                }
            }
        }

        openModal(data) {
            ...
            this.refs.modal.open();
        }

        closeModal() {
            this.refs.modal.close();
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <Modal ref={"modal"} ...>
                    ...
                </Modal>
            );
        }
    }

    const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
        return {
            modalOpen: state.modal.isOpen
        }
    }

    export default connect(mapStateToProps, { openModal, closeModal })(Summary);
```

Comment: can u give example of what you mean? don't understand connecting modal.js

Comment: I added an example

Comment: thank you! still having issue though. The modal is not being triggered. no breakpoints are being hit in the componenet

Comment: I just added the updated reducer. the action.payload.data is populated correctly

Comment: the isOpen boolean is changing to true. I can see that in the redux debugger.

Comment: Can you see if the `componentWillReceiveProps` lifecycle method fires?

Comment: doesnt fire. just double checked with a alert

Comment: this means your mapStateToProps function doesn't work correctly, you should put a debugger there and see if it got triggered (sets the values correctly) Do you only have the boolean value of open or closed connected?

Comment: ok I put a debugger inside the maptoStateProps function. nothing happened. So I made a plunker that has files that I am using for this. It is a template I started with. Also on the index.android.js you will see 3 links to screenshot images I took of the redux debugger... also I have renamed some of the functions from my original post